# Is there an efficient way of using "cross_df" or "expand.grid" in a loop to get around vector allocation size limit in R?

Tags: r

I get an **error** when using `cross_df` or `expand.grid` to get all combinations for large vectors :

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- 1:100000
y <- 1:100000

coords <- list(long = x,
               lat = y)

cross_df(coords)

#> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.3 Gb
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I tried an alternative way using `map` and `bind_rows` but this is very slow and never finishes :

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- 1:100000
y <- 1:100000

f.cross <- function(i){coords <- list(long = i, 
                                       lat = y)
                        
                      coords %>% cross_df}


x %>% map(f.cross) %>% bind_rows()
```

Is there a faster or a more efficient way to produce a table of all combinations for large vectors without getting a size limit error?

```
#> R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)
```

Comment: You may want to read `help('Memory-limits')`.

Comment: If your problem is a grid search, maybe go back to the [original problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) it is meant to solve. You can also see if a [disk.frame](https://rpubs.com/xiaodai/intro-disk-frame) can be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that solves my problem. The idea is to create a database of my combinations by subsetting the work into smaller operations. For this I use a double `for` loop :

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
  
grid_db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(),
                     dbname= "stack.db")

df_x <- tibble(x = 1:100000,
               iteration = ntile(x,100))


df_y <- tibble (y = 1:100000,
                iteration = ntile(y,100))

for (i in 1:100) {
  
    for (j in 1:100){
    
              # pull subset of coordinates
              x <- df_x %>% filter(iteration == i) %>% pull(x)
              y <- df_y %>% filter(iteration == j) %>% pull(y)
              
              # expand.grid on the subset of coordinates
              subset_grid <- expand.grid(x, y) %>% as_tibble() 
              
              # append database with subset of combinations
              dbWriteTable(conn = grid_db,
                           name = "xy_combinations",
                           value =  subset_grid, 
                           append = TRUE)
                    }
                }
```

It produces an above 50Gb database. Note that it may be slow to filter through it.